# Android SQLite Database CREATE TABLE Error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How can I solve these problems?

> Process: com.example.burhanozen.sqlitedb, PID: 4658
>                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INTEGER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE
>   students_table (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,SURNAME
>   TEXT,MARK INTEGER
>
> -at com.example.burhanozen.sqlitedb.dbHelper.onCreate(dbHelper.kt:16)
>   -at com.example.burhanozen.sqlitedb.dbHelper.insertData(dbHelper.kt:28)
>   -at com.example.burhanozen.sqlitedb.MainActivity$addData$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:62)

This is Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    internal val helper = dbHelper(this)


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    addData()


    viewAll()


    }

    fun viewAll(){
        kayitGoster.setOnClickListener{
            val res = helper.allData
            if(res.count == 0){
                showMessage("Hata","Veri bulunamadı")
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            val buffer = StringBuffer()
            while(res.moveToNext()){
                buffer.append("Id : " + res.getString(0) + "\n")
                buffer.append("Name : " + res.getString(1) + "\n")
                buffer.append("Surname : " + res.getString(2) + "\n")
                buffer.append("Mark : " + res.getString(3) + "\n")


            }




        }
    }

    fun showMessage(title:String, message:String){
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setCancelable(true)
        builder.setTitle(title)
        builder.setMessage(message)
        builder.show()

    }



    fun addData(){
        gonderButon.setOnClickListener {
            helper.insertData(
                    editisim.text.toString(),
                    soyisim.text.toString(),
                    not.text.toString())

        }

    }



}
```

And here is dbHelper.kt

```
class dbHelper (context : Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1) {


    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "NAME TEXT," +
                "SURNAME TEXT," +
                "MARK INTEGER")
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db:SQLiteDatabase,oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME")
        onCreate(db)
    }

    fun insertData(name:String, surname:String, marks:String){
        val db=this.writableDatabase
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(COL_NAME,name)
        contentValues.put(COL_SURN,surname)
        contentValues.put(COL_NOT,marks)
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues)
    }

    val allData: Cursor
        get(){
            val db=this.writableDatabase
            val res=db.rawQuery("select * from $TABLE_NAME",null)
            return res
        }


    companion object{

        internal val DATABASE_NAME = "students.db"
        internal val TABLE_NAME = "students_table"
        internal val COL_ID = "ID"
        internal val COL_NAME = "NAME"
        internal val COL_SURN = "SURNAME"
        internal val COL_NOT = "MARKS"
    }
}
```

Comment: use `MARK INTEGER` https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the close parenthesis in your SQL statement. What you have right now is:

```
Create(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "NAME TEXT," +
        "SURNAME TEXT," +
        "MARK INTEGER")
```

That needs to be:

```
Create(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "NAME TEXT," +
        "SURNAME TEXT," +
        "MARK INTEGER)")
```